# Simplify "if var1 in string or var2 in string:" in Python

Tags: python

Is there simpler than

```
if var1 in string or var2 in string:
```

I try that:

```
if (var1 or var2) in string:
```

But that doesn't work...

Thanks in advance !

Comment: its look pretty good, efficient and simplest.

Comment: Why do you need it simplified? The original is clear and concise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [any](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
if any(x in string for x in (var1, var2))
```

**any(iterable)**
Return True if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is empty, return False

As pointed out in the comments for two vars your own solution is as simple as you will get but in my opinion if you have 3 or more vars then `any` is a by far nicer and more concise solution.

Comment: While this works, it's arguably not as good as the original. You have to think a bit more about the code to understand what it's doing. The original is more clear, though this scales better if you're checking for more variables than just two.

Comment: @BryanOakley, yes but if you have any understanding of python then it is going to be pretty clear and is the closest working solution to `if (var1 or var2) in string:` the OP is going to get.

Comment: n.p. - this is not really a simplification of the condition in the OP, however, if there were more search strings, `any()` could be clearer and more concise.

Answer (score -2):

If you are open to using regular expressions,

```
import re
re.search(r'('+v1+'|'+v2+')',s)
```

This doesn't look any more elegant that your solution, but it can be useful if you have lots of substrings to search:

```
import re
v = ['abc', 'drf', 'nasd', 'djk', 'po2-pe']
re.search(r'('+'|'.join(v)+')',s)
```

Comment: This could fail for a whole lot of real-world values of `v1` and `v2`.

Comment: True, but you can fix that with `re.escape()`. Granted, that makes this even less concise and elegant than the original.

Comment: re.escape() has an alternative: use the search string as a raw string. That's what the 'r' is doing.

Comment: @arvindpdmn: the `r` only protects the data from being interpreted by python, and the way you're using it it's only affecting the first parenthesis. If there is, say, a pipe or unbalanced parenthesis, the re will fail or will yield unexpected results.

Comment: @arvindpdmn: you're mixing things. The 'r' is for not treating '\' as a special character, all the regular expression special characters stay the same, otherwise `(` or `|` wouldn't work either.